# Bootstrap 4, Flexbox| How to make <li> elements fit to containers width

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm having a lot of issues with trying to stretch out my li elements to fit the width of the container. I've tried messing with the widths of each individual li and messing around with other Flexbox utilities to try to get it working but to no avail. **So, how would I be able to change the width of each li to fit the width of the container, as in the same width as the** ***To do List*** **header and the text box?**

Here is a picture of the webpage:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WgR9.png

And then here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* W3C */
}

.heading {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.item {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.header {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center heading">
                <h1 class="ml-4 header">TO-DO LIST</h1>
                <h4><i class="fa fa-plus mr-2 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
            </div>
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <input class= "pb-5"type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="row d-flex no-gutter">
                <div class="d-flex row item"><li><span>X</span> Row 1</li></div>
                <div class="d-flex row item"><li><span>X</span> Row 2</li></div>
                <div class="d-flex row item"><li><span>X</span> Row 3</li></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is just wrong in some places, and consider taking advantage of existing Bootstrap layout classes to get the same effect. See result below, I think it's more like what you are after. Cheers

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #2BC0E4 10%, #EAECC6 90%); /* W3C */
}

.heading {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}

.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
}

.list-group li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.header {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center heading">
      <h1 class="ml-4 header">TO-DO LIST</h1>
      <h4><i class="fa fa-plus mr-2 mt-2" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <input class="pb-5" type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
  </div>
  <ul class="row list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><span>X</span> Row 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span>X</span> Row 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span>X</span> Row 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no estas siguiendo el patron de diseño de bootstrap, que es el siguiente:

Apparently you are not following the bootstrap design pattern, which is as follows:

```
root-body
    div->.container
        div->.row
          div->.column
            div->.row
              ul->.list w-100
                 li/ul->.your-classname w-100
```

En tu ejemplo, no estas agregando el div con el column y el hijo row con las clase w-100 de bootstrap para forzar el elemento a que utilice el 100% del ancho de la pantalla.

In your example, you are not adding the div with the column and the row child with the bootstrap w-100 classes to force the element to use 100% of the screen width.